# Type a function declaration

Tags: typescript

Given this type definition

```
type MyFunction = (prop: string) => boolean
```

I know it's possible to type an anonymous function

```
const myFunction: MyFunction = (prop) => true
```

But I'm not sure on how to do this for a regular function definition

```
function myFunction (prop) {
  return true;
}
```

Is this possible, and if so how? Thanks

EDIT

Just to clarify, I'm looking for a way to type the function using the same type definition, and not broken down inside the function, if it's at all possible. The main reason is to be able to re-use the type definition in other places.. callbacks, declaration files etc

Comment: What do you mean by _"I'm looking for a way to type the function"_?

Comment: Just FWIW, as of JavaScript ES2015, the "anonymous" function above isn't anonymous. (The expression on the right of the `=` is an anonymous function expression, but the resulting function is not anonymous, it has a true name inferred -- per spec -- from the constant's name.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this

```
function myFunction (prop: string) : boolean {
  return true;
}
```

EDIT
If you want to make a reusable function type, then you have to create your functions as variables, i.e. `const myFunc: FuncType = function(param: string) : boolean { ... }`. You can't do that with declarative `function ()` syntax without creating a variable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've edited my question to be more specific on what I'm looking for

Comment: So you can't use a type on a function declaration to define the function's type? You either have to just type its parts so it matches your type, or assign to a constant/variable/property instead?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder pretty much, yes